# Exception setting Imagebutton view on Android 2.3.4

Tags: android

I've been running my app on Android 4.0 and it works just fine. However, I tested it on a phone running Android 2.3.4 and the app crashed. I throws an exception when it tries to set the Imagebutton view:

```
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.motesclient/com.example.motesclient.ConnectActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:209)
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741):     at com.example.motesclient.ConnectActivity.onCreate(ConnectActivity.java:27)
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741):     ... 11 more
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741):     ... 22 more
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x101030e a=-1}
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1681)
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1961)
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:112)
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741):     at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:85)
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741):     at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:81)
03-07 17:21:58.789: E/AndroidRuntime(5741):     ... 25 more
```

this is the Imagebutton:

```
<ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/connect_button"
     android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
     android:contentDescription="@string/connect_picture"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:src="@drawable/connectxml"/>
```

And here is the connectxml.xml file, which is placed in the drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_pressed="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/connectbuttonpressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
        <item android:state_focused="true"
         android:drawable="@drawable/connectbuttonpressed" /> <!-- focused -->
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/connectbutton" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Any idea as to how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your using something that didn't exist in api 9 (2.3):

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

You can go to your android platform folder and see what is supported for the given version. It's located in:

`android-sdk\platforms\android-9\data\res\values\attr.xml`.

**Reedit**

A possible solution would be remove the line that gives the problem and instead add:

```
style="@style/Custom.ImageButton"
```

Then add a `styles.xml` to `res/values` looking like this:

```
<resources>
   <style name="Custom.ImageButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.ImageButton">
       <item name="android:background">@drawable/your_own_graphic</item>
   </style>
</resources>
```

And a `styles.xml` to `res/values-14` looking like this:

```
   <style name="Custom.ImageButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.ImageButton">
       <item name="android:background">?android:attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
   </style>
```

I'm sorry about the prior suggestion which was wrong.

Comment: It worked! is there something similar to `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` for api 9?

Comment: @user2071976 I don't know :(

Comment: Could you explain it in more detail?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what I should do. Should I copy the attr.xml file from `android-sdk\platforms\android-16\data\res\values\attr.xml`to `res/values` and `res/values-9`? How can I make res/values point to `?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroun` and `res/values-9` point to `connectbutton`?

Comment: @user2071976 Updated the solution to something that works (tested it)

Answer (score 2):

Everything looks right to me.  I would try just cleaning the project.

Assuming you are using Eclipse: Project -> Clean -> clean all

Sometimes eclipse fails to update R.java with the latest xml changes.

Comment: Hmm. Do you have your xml drawable defined in just /res/drawable/ ?

Comment: If you backtrack to debug it, and set the imageButton's drawable to @drawable/connectbutton  does it work then?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, could you explain it to me again pls?

Comment: Please avoid internet slang like "pls".

Change: android:src="@drawable/connectxml" to android:src="@drawable/connectbutton"

So that it references the image directly